# jQuery qTip adjust scroll and target mouse

Tags: jquery, scroll, qtip

How I can use qTip plugin ( http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/ ) with target mouse and scroll adjust false?

I put my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3XyZL/
Just click into div and scroll down or up. I want that qtip don't move.

My qtip configs are:

```
$('#chart_div').qtip({
    position: {
        adjust: { 
            mouse : false,
            scroll: false
        },
        target: 'mouse'
    },
    style: { width: { min: 485 } },
    content:{
        title: {
            text: 'TITLE',
            button: 'X'
        },
    },
    show:{
        when : false
    },
    hide: { when: 'click'}
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you wan the qtip to move up and down as you scroll on the page?

Comment: I want that qTip don't move, stay where I clicked, thx

Comment: So you are ok with it going off screen when you scroll the window?

Comment: When I run the fiddle it currently opens where you click the mouse then when scrolling the page the qtip doesn't move.

Comment: Mark, yes, but when I scroll, tooltip follow mouse, and I don't want it, finally I solved it, using qTip2, it's beta and also had to do tricks, but finally works. Anyway, I thank Craig for his work

Comment: Thanks for all Marrk, I solved it updating to new qTip version. :)